# How can I dynamically count an object wether it's paginated or not?

Tags: ruby, pagination

I have two arrays: `products` and `services` in a partial. They may or may not be paginated so I need to be able to count them wether they are or not. `products.total_count` works if it's paginated but not if it is isn't. While `products.count` works if it is not paginated but not when it is. The same goes for `services`. I need something that will work for both.

Comment: paginated = products.respond_to?(:total_count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
products.try(:count) || products.total_count
```

Be sure to use the more common case on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use respond_to?(method), to check if you can use it.

So in your case it's something like:

```
if products.respond_to?(:total_count)
  products.total_count
else
  products.total
end
```